# AttributeError: <Class> object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this class:

```
class MyManager():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__sock_service = ClientSocket()

    def say_hello(self, request: Dict):
        self.__sock_service.send(request['name'])
        return self.__sock_service.receive()
```

When calling say_hello method, I get

```
"AttributeError: MyManager object has no attribute __sock_service".
```

Though, I do have an object _MyManager.__sock_service that is initialized (plus, my server does recognize a new connection).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the full traceback you get.

Comment: Maybe it didn't happen when you call `say_hello`, but `MyManager().__sock_service', if so, please refer https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: A `_MyManager` is not a `MyManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full code?
If not please write the full code